# Verilog code task inputs do not match the passed values

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, adder

I am using a `task` in my `module` in Verilog, and I have a problem in passing the argument values.  The variables defined in the task block as input are not receiving the values that are passed to them while calling this task.

Here is the code:

```
module carry_addr(Cin,A,B,Sum, Cout,rst_n );
parameter width=3;
parameter bits=1;
input [width:0] A,B;
input Cin,rst_n;
output reg [width:0] Sum;
output reg Cout;
integer k;

reg [width+1:0]C2;
      
task fulladder;
input A1;
input B1;
input C4;
output reg Sum1;
output reg C0;
begin
        Sum1=0;
        C0=0;
        {C0,Sum1}=A1+B1+C4;
end 
endtask

task automatic ripple;
input [bits:0] A2;
input [bits:0] B2;
input C1;
output reg [bits:0]sum2;
output reg cout;
reg [bits:0]sum3,sum4;
reg [bits+1:0] C,C3;
begin
            sum2=0;
            sum3=0;
            sum4=0;
           cout=0;
            C=0;
            C3=0;
        
            C[0]=0;        
            C3[0]=1;
            for (k=0;k<=bits;k=k+1)
            begin 
                 fulladder(A2[k],B2[k],C[k],sum3[k],C[k+1]);
                 fulladder(A2[k],B2[k],C3[k],sum4[k],C3[k+1]);
            end
            if(C1==0)
            begin
                cout=C[bits+1];
                sum2=sum3;
            end
            else if(C1==1)
            begin
                cout=C3[bits+1];
                sum2=sum4;
            end
end
endtask

always@(rst_n or A or B or Cin)
begin
    if(!rst_n)
     begin
            Sum=0;
            Cout=0;
            C2=0;
     end
    
         C2[0]=Cin;
         for (k=0;k<=width;k=k+bits+1)
         begin
              ripple(A[k+:bits],B[k+:bits],C2[k],Sum[k+:bits],C2[k+bits+1]);
         end
         Cout=C2[width+1];
end

endmodule
```

In this specifically, `A` and `B` values are not copying in the `A2` and `B2` variables in the `ripple` `task`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have a bit width mismatch between the `ripple` task input signal and the value you pass to the task.

You declared the `A2` input as a 2-bit signal, but you pass it a 1-bit signal.  You can prove this to yourself by using `$bit` to display the bit width of each signal.

Add this line inside the `begin` block in the task:

```
$display($size(A2));
```

Then add this line inside the `begin` block right before you call the `ripple` task:

```
$display($size(A[k+:bits]));
```

`$size(A2)` shows 2.

`$size(A[k+:bits])` shows 1.

For example, when `k`=0, `A[k+:bits]` resolves to `A[0 +: 1]` which is the same as `A[0:0]` or `A[0]`.  That is a 1-bit value.

There is another problem, too.  I created a simple testbench to drive some values into the design.  For some reason,  the `for` loop inside the `always` block only executes once.  It should execute twice (`k` = 0 and 2).  It is not worth debugging this code because you really need a whole new approach.  You should re-write the code without using tasks.  It is far more common to use Verilog tasks in testbench code than it is in design code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be stemming from the fact that you don't have any delays in the verilog code under the for loop (including the code included in the tasks). There could be multiple driver issue.

You can try adding #1 in your for loop and see if that helps.

I notice that the question is pretty old. Might be useful for future exchangers.

Comment: Adding delays will not solve the problem.  It is uncommon for design code to use `#` delays.